# Unknown function: vundle#begin

Tags: linux, vim, vundle

I had old vundle installed. Instead of using `git pull` to update vundle, I removed old vundle from `~/.vim` and installed it following Quick Start section in the [Github page of vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim).

Maybe I broke something when I installed new vundle. I get this:

```
jack@Jack-PC ~ $ vim .vimrc
Error detected while processing /home/jack/.vimrc:
line    6:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line   15:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I followed the instructions on the Github page exactly.

```
" .vimrc
set nocompatible
filetype off 

" Vundle 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
"
"" Vundle Plugins List
"Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
"Plugin 'php.vim'
"Plugin 'neocomplcache'
"Plugin 'rails.vim'
"Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
"
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

maybe the rtp location is wrong,you can type

```
:echo &rtp
```

in Vim to see whether the location of `~` stand for is correct.

you can replace

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

to

```
set rtp+=/home/[YourUserName]/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim   //do not use ~
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For gVim users: `set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim`

Comment: Amazing solution. Looks like this is usually the case when setting up `.vimrc` files in remote linux servers with multiple users.

Answer (score 64):

Your .vimrc seems fine. Looks like you have not installed the vundle plugin properly.
Run this command on your console.

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

You should have a directory structure like (I simplified it):

```
~/.vim
├── bundle/
│   └── Vundle.vim  <------------------ Vundle
├── colors/
│   └── Tomorrow.vim
└── plugin/
    └── acp.vim
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`?

Comment: This worked for me, I ran into this issue after copying my .vimrc from one computer to another.

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue again. 
After checked, the reason why is that there is more than one bundle environment in computer, you can :echo &rtp, and see other environment, and remove other bundle directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is:

```
set rtp+=$HOME/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim " in OS X
```

of course, you can find out: `echo $HOME`, is it your home directory or not.